# Macro that consolidates multiple workbooks, working on excel 2010 but not on 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that consolidates a number of workbooks into a single consolidated file. Originally it was a copying and pasting but I changed it thinking the copying and pasting was too heavy on the computer and was causing it to crash. After successfully implementing the changes the macro continues to fail after cycling through around the 50th workbook. Any insight into with why my excel crashes (closes and opens) using this macro is greatly appreciated.

Note: This macro works on a peer's computer who uses excel 2010

```
Dim TargetFolder As String, TargetFile As String
Dim wsConsol As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long, DestLastRow As Long
Dim TranRange As Variant

'Sets the name of the wsConsol file, if required
Set wsConsol = Workbooks("Consolidation File.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Data")

'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
   TargetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
   Err.Clear
End With

'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and status bar updates to help code run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder you selected
'and then close that file before opening the next file

TargetFile = Dir(TargetFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

Do While TargetFile <> ""
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo 0
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=TargetFolder & "\" & TargetFile, UpdateLinks:=False

             ''''''''''''START CODE HERE TO DO SOMETHING'''''''''

    'Find the last row in the wsConsol file
    DestLastRow = wsConsol.Cells(wsConsol.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


    wsConsol.Range("A" & DestLastRow).Value = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("B22:B22").Value


    wsConsol.Range("AD" & DestLastRow).Value = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("B17:B17").Value


    wsConsol.Range("B" & DestLastRow).Value = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("B20:B20").Value



    TranRange = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("D25:L25").Value
    TranRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TranRange)
    wsConsol.Range("C" & DestLastRow & ":K" & DestLastRow).Value = TranRange


    TranRange = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("F17:F22").Value
    TranRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TranRange)
    wsConsol.Range("L" & DestLastRow & ":Q" & DestLastRow).Value = TranRange


    TranRange = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("G17:G22").Value
    TranRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TranRange)
    wsConsol.Range("R" & DestLastRow & ":W" & DestLastRow).Value = TranRange


    TranRange = Workbooks(TargetFile).Worksheets("Summary").Range("H17:H22").Value
    TranRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TranRange)
    wsConsol.Range("X" & DestLastRow & ":AD" & DestLastRow).Value = TranRange

    ''''''''''''END CODE HERE THAT DID SOMETHING'''''''''

    'Close TargetFile Workbook
    Workbooks(TargetFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
    TargetFile = Dir
Loop

'turns settings back on that you turned off before looping folders
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using the same folder as your colleague?

Comment: I had a similar issue once and found that it was consistently failing on the exact same book. When I ran the macro on just that book alone I found the specific workbook was corrupted and caused crashes. Worked fine after excluding that book. No clue if that is the issue here but may be worth checking on

Comment: This task could be more efficiently handled by using [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which is native in Excel 2016. I have read [several posts](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=vba+excel+consolidation+multiple+files+crashing+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ACYBGNSqrZLhzaP05ZUTNmv042Ky5DKIHw:1578687830156&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMmc-67vnmAhUEx1kKHQ1jBqcQrQIoAjACegQIChAN&biw=1920&bih=933) about this issue and a lot of them are about just workarounds.

Comment: @Warcupine yes I am using the same source folder. He can move the folder to his desktop or access it on our drive and it works regardless for him

Comment: @urdearboy It is consistently failing around the same file so that may be it I will further investigate.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I am not too familiar with power query but will look into it if it is native to excel 2016.

Comment: Sure! shoot us a message if you need any help.